# SpagoBI 5 JDBC installation in remote server

Tags: mysql, jdbc, business-intelligence, spagobi

Does anyone know, how to connect our data source to Spagobi running on a remote server? What is the path to install jdbc mysql drivers in SpagoBI 5?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SpagoBI have some limitations when connecting to external datasources. Spagobi only supports databases with jdbc or jndi. Path will be configured after installing the above drivers